# Return Only the Keys from Document Where the Query condition was True

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm having group of elements in MongoDB as given below:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5942643ea2042e12245de00c"),
    "user": NumberInt(1),
    "name": {
        "value": "roy",
        "time": NumberInt(121)
    },
    "lname": {
        "value": "roy s",
        "time": NumberInt(122)
    },
    "sname": {
        "value": "roy 9",
        "time": NumberInt(123)
    }
}
```

but when I execute the query below

```
db.temp.find({
    $or: [{
        'name.time': {
            $gte: 123
        }
    }, {
        'lname.time': {
            $gte: 123
        }
    }, {
        'sname.time': {
            $gte: 123
        }
    }]
})
```

it is returning the whole document which is correct.

Is there any way to fetch only specified object in which condition matched.Like in my document let condition within lname.time equl to 122 then only lname object will return rest will ignored.

Comment: Trying to understand the question. You are asking if "either" of these field is "greater than" the supplied value then the document is meant to be returned. That is intentional correct? Are you now also asking that you only want to see certain fields in returned documents if other conditions are also true? So here just the `lname` and no other fields because it has the correct value, and other documents would contain "all" fields?

Comment: From my query only **sname** is correct object.so is there to return only specified condition true objects.

Comment: Cracker of a question really. Pitty that people just jumped onto it without understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of thing you are asking for is only really "practical" with MongoDB 3.4 in order to return this from the server.

### Summary

The general case here is that the "projection" of fields by logical conditions is not straightforward. Whilst it would be nice if MongoDB had such a DSL for projection, this is basically delegated either to:

- Do your manipulation "after" the results are returned from the server
- Use the aggregation pipeline in order to manipulate the documents.

Therefore, in "CASE B" being "aggregation pipeline", this is really only a practical excercise if the steps involved "mimic" the standard `.find()` behavior of "query" and "project". Introducing other pipeline stages beyond that will only introduce performance problems greatly outweighing any gain from "trimming" the documents to return.

Thus the summary here is `$match` then `$newRoot` to "project", following the pattern. It is also I think a good *"rule of thumb"* to consider here that the aggregation approach "should only" be applied where there is a significant reduction in the size of data returned. I would expand by example saying that *"if"* the size of the keys to "trim" was actually in the Megabytes range on the returned result, then it is a worthwhile exercise to remove them "on the server".

In the case where such a saving would really only constitute "bytes" in comparison, then the most logical course is to simply allow the documents to return in the cursor "un-altered", and only then in "post processing" would you bother removing unwanted keys that did not meet the logical condition.

That said, On with the actual methods.

### Aggregation Case

```
db.temp.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "$or": [
      { "name.time": { "$gte": 123 } },
      { "lname.time": { "$gte": 123 } },
      { "sname.time": { "$gte": 123  } }
    ]        
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
     "newRoot": {
       "$arrayToObject": {
         "$concatArrays": [
           [
             { "k": "_id", "v": "$_id" },
             { "k": "user", "v": "$user" },
           ],
           { "$filter": {
             "input": [
               { "$cond": [ 
                 { "$gte": [ "$name.time", 123 ] },
                 { "k": "name", "v": "$name" },
                 false
               ]},
               { "$cond": [ 
                 { "$gte": [ "$lname.time", 123 ] },
                 { "k": "lname", "v": "$lname" },
                 false
               ]},
               { "$cond": [ 
                 { "$gte": [ "$sname.time", 123 ] },
                 { "k": "sname", "v": "$sname" },
                 false
               ]}
             ],
             "as": "el",
             "cond": "$$el"
           }}
         ]
       }
     }
  }}
])
```

It's a pretty fancy statement that relies on `$arrayToObject` and `$replaceRoot` to achieve the dynamic structure. At its core the "keys" are all represented in array form, where the "array" only contains those keys that actually pass the conditions.

Fully constructed after the conditions are filtered we turn the array into a document and return the projection to the new Root.

### Cursor Processing Case

You can actually do this in the client code with ease though. For example in JavaScript:

```
db.temp.find({
  "$or": [
    { "name.time": { "$gte": 123 } },
    { "lname.time": { "$gte": 123 } },
    { "sname.time": { "$gte": 123  } }
  ]        
}).map(doc => {
  if ( doc.name.time  < 123 )
    delete doc.name;
  if ( doc.lname.time < 123 )
    delete doc.lname;
  if ( doc.sname.time < 123 )
    delete doc.sname;
  return doc;
})
```

In both cases you get the same desired result:

```
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5942643ea2042e12245de00c"),
            "user" : 1,
            "sname" : {
                    "value" : "roy 9",
                    "time" : 123
            }
    }
```

Where `sname` was the only field to meet the condition in the document and therefore the only one returned.

---

### Dynamic Generation and DSL Re-use

Addressing Sergio's question then I suppose you can actually re-use the DSL from the `$or` condition to generate in both cases:

Considering the variable defined

```
var orlogic = [
        {
                "name.time" : {
                        "$gte" : 123
                }
        },
        {
                "lname.time" : {
                        "$gte" : 123
                }
        },
        {
                "sname.time" : {
                        "$gte" : 123
                }
        }
];
```

Then with cursor iteration:

```
db.temp.find({
  "$or": orlogic  
}).map(doc => {
  orlogic.forEach(cond => {
    Object.keys(cond).forEach(k => {
      var split = k.split(".");
      var op = Object.keys(cond[k])[0];
      if ( op === "$gte" && doc[split[0]][split[1]] < cond[k][op] )
        delete doc[split[0]];
      else if ( op === "$lte" && doc[split[0]][split[1]] > cond[k][op] )
        delete doc[split[0]];
    })
  });
  return doc;
})
```

Which evaluates against the DSL to actually perform the operations without "hardcoded" ( somewhat ) `if` statements;

Then the aggregation approach would also be:

```
var pipeline = [
  { "$match": { "$or": orlogic } },
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          [
            { "k": "_id", "v": "$_id" },
            { "k": "user", "v": "$user" }
          ],
          { "$filter": {
            "input": orlogic.map(cond => {
              var obj = { 
                "$cond": {
                  "if": { },
                  "then": { },
                  "else": false
                }
              };
              Object.keys(cond).forEach(k => {
                var split = k.split(".");
                var op = Object.keys(cond[k])[0];
                obj.$cond.if[op] = [ `$${k}`, cond[k][op] ];
                obj.$cond.then = { "k": split[0], "v": `$${split[0]}` };
              });
              return obj;
            }),
            "as": "el",
            "cond": "$$el"
          }}
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
];

db.test.aggregate(pipeline);
```

So the same basic conditions where we re-use existing `$or` DSL to generate the required pipeline parts as opposed to hard coding them in.

Comment: Interesting solution. I guess, we can't avoid the duplication of logic in the query.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Well I "guess" we could apply the existing `$or` condition logic DSL to generate for both cases, if that is what you mean. Added somewhat of a "short" take on doing that. Thanks for the grammar correct BTW. Speak well doughnut tired when am I ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to find specifies the fields to return (projection)

```
db.collection.find(query, projection)
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

as in example

```
db.bios.find( { }, { name: 1, contribs: 1 } )
```

Comment: i have three object name i.e. name,lname,sname . in my OR query condition i will send time as parameter let say 123 then this time only sname is correct object so only that will returned not any other that are not matched. i can't set any fix field in projection parameter.

Comment: This answer does appear to have missed the point of the question, which in all fairness could have been clearer. It's since had a makeover to the title at least to reflect the intention. I think you would agree on reflection that this present *"read the fine manual"* response does not address the issue that was actually asked being related to *"conditional projection of fields"* which has been addressed in other answers. So the manual citation is really not at place here. For your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.temp.find({
  "$elemMatch": "$or"[
    {
      'name.time': {
        $gte: 123
      }
    },
    {
      'lname.time': {
        $gte: 123
      }
    },
    {
      'sname.time': {
        $gte: 123
      }
    }
  ]
},
{
  {
    "name.time": 1,
    "lname.time": 1,
    "sname.time": 1
  }
}
})
```

Comment: missed curly braces :-  db.temp.find({"$elemMatch": {"$or"[{
'name.time': {
        $gte: 123
      }
}, {
    'lname.time': {
        $gte: 123
    }
}, {
    'sname.time': {
        $gte: 123
    }
}]
}, {{"name.time": 1,"lname.time":1, "sname.time":1 }}

})

Comment: Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'unknown top level operator: $elemMatch' on server localhost:27017

Comment: Just so you know [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) only applies to arrays. These are not arrays. But basically you missed the whole point of the question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

My approach using aggregation pipeline

[$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) - Project is used to create an key for the documents name, sname and lname

Initial project Query

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$project: {_id:1, "tempname.name": "$name", "templname.lname":"$lname", "tempsname.sname":"$sname"}}]);
```

Result of this query is

```
{"_id":ObjectId("5942643ea2042e12245de00c"),"tempname":{"name":{"value":"roy","time":121}},"templname":{"lname":{"value":"roy s","time":122}},"tempsname":{"sname":{"value":"roy 9","time":123}}}
```

Use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) one more time to add the documents into an array

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$project: {_id:1, "tempname.name": "$name", "templname.lname":"$lname", "tempsname.sname":"$sname"}}, 
{$project: {names: ["$tempname", "$templname", "$tempsname"]}}])
```

Our document will be like this after the execution of second project

```
{"_id":ObjectId("5942643ea2042e12245de00c"),"names":[{"name":{"value":"roy","time":121}},{"lname":{"value":"roy s","time":122}},{"sname":{"value":"roy 9","time":123}}]}
```

Then use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to break the array into separate documents

after breaking the documents use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) with $or to get the desired result

**

> Final Query

**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      "tempname.name": "$name",
      "templname.lname": "$lname",
      "tempsname.sname": "$sname"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      names: [
        "$tempname",
        "$templname",
        "$tempsname"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$names"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "names.name.time": {
            $gte: 123
          }
        },
        {
          "names.lname.time": {
            $gte: 123
          }
        },
        {
          "names.sname.time": {
            $gte: 123
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Final result of the query closer to your expected result(with an additional key)

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5942643ea2042e12245de00c"),
        "names" : {
                "sname" : {
                        "value" : "roy 9",
                        "time" : 123
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Well yeah, **BUT**! [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is going to essentially create **"three'** copies of the document for every document analysed by the query operation, adding to that an additional pass through the whole collection in order to project the array to "unwind". So before you even get to the actual query for selection you have 1. Processed the entire collection and not matching entries 2. Created "three times" the document load to analyse and filter.

Comment: The point is that the "query" is the most important thing and the operation "should" just perform on par with a regular query. This will not. Even with an initial `$match` to make it a little better, what you propose effectively turns a 10,000 document scan into a 30,000 document scan. Plus quite a bit more change. That's why I only proposed things that effectively work as a "single pass". Just like `.find()`, and in fact that would be the recommended method. Simply find, and re-shape in post processing.

Comment: @NeilLunn - My query is not good on performance on a larger collection, since $match should be used at initial stage of aggregate pipeline to have better performance. Your solution for this problem is looks interesting and will have a better performance. Even the item $replaceRoot are new to myself. Thanks Neil for the additional inputs.

Comment: Thanks yourself. And of course I'm not saying *"It does not work"* which of course I acknowledge it does. It's just that *"should you use this in production?"*. I think not, and hence the comments for everyone's clarity. I only just added some additional info to the answer I gave, re: DSL Re-use if you care to give that a read also.